# How do I change the location of ejb-jar.xml in my maven project?

Tags: java, maven-2, ejb

When building my EJB project with maven, maven expects the ejb-jar.xml to be in META-INF/.  However; I need to be able to put it in directoryA/META-INF.

maven-ejb-plugin doesn't seem to provide a parameter for specifying where ejb-jar.xml is.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: It was more because Maven 1 has a property for that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the *maven-ejb-plugin* doesn't provide any parameter to change the location of the deployment descriptor which is expected to be available at `META-INF/ejb-jar.xml` (the location is hard coded in the EjbMojo) or the build will fail at packaging time when building EJB 2.X (which makes sense).

So, one way to achieve your goal would be to use the *maven-antrun-plugin* before the packaging phase to copy the content of `directoryA` (assuming `directoryA` was in a resources directory like `src/main/resources` and has been copied to `target/classes`) to the expected location (i.e. the root of `target/classes`) and do some clean up, something like this:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <configuration>
        <tasks>
          <copy todir="${project.build.outputDirectory}">
            <fileset dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}/directoryA"/> 
          </copy>
          <delete dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}/directoryA"/>
        </tasks>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I don't find this very clean but it works.

Comment: I ended up having to use this method (even though I don't like it any more than you do.)  Had to rearrange some of the calls (making a directory first, etc), but the basic idea worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Plugin look for the ejb-jar.xml in the build.outputdirectory/META-INF as I could see in the pligin source file
**private static final String EJB_JAR_XML = "META-INF/ejb-jar.xml";** 
It is possible to copy reqiured ejb-xml using the resource plugin

....

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF</outputDirectory>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/META-INF</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do the same thing and got it to work by simply adding an additional resource directory to the 'build' section of the POM (which is in additon to the default location of java/main/resources):

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/directoryA</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
...
</build>
```

Answer (score -1):

Wont the "outputDirectory" configuration property work (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/ejb-mojo.html#outputDirectory)? I see that it has been suggested in the antrun example mentioned earlier; however, this config property is available in the ejb plugin-itself (see the link). Or, are you saying you ONLY want the ejb-jar.xml to be moved?

Comment: No - output directory would change the location of the output file.  I need to change the location of the INPUT file (where it gets the file from, not where it puts the output when the build is complete.)